# Create Externalized Configuration in spring-boot along with profiles

Tags: spring-boot, config, app-config, spring-annotations

I have a spring-boot application with annotations instead of `context.xml`.

In my `src/main/resources` folder I have: `application-dev.properties` and `application-test.properties`.

which work perfectly for different profiles (while running with VM option like `-Dspring.profiles.active=dev`)

Now I need to externalize this properties with file in `/opt/software/Tomcat8/conf/app.properties`

Some props override each other, some don't.

in Tomcat config context.xml I say:

```
<Environment name="app.properties"
    value="file:///opt/software/Tomcat8/conf/app.properties"
    type="java.lang.String" override="false"/>
```

How to use it via JNDI in my application configuring app with no XML but annotations in Spring-bot application class?

I need it to have priority to inner jar properties according to 
[Link to Spring-boot.doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html)

Comment: rename the property in JNDI to `SPRING_CONFIG_LOCATION` or `spring.config.location`.

Comment: Thanks! but unfortunately it didnt work for me... Properties now exist in context environment, but outer file props dont prevail over inner jar props.

Comment: Show us relevant parts of your configuration

Comment: Probably the thing is that (according to [link]https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html) hardnamed props files have less prioriy than profile-specific inner props. So now I am trying to write value of my SPRING_CONFIG_LOCATION propertys smth like application-${profile}.properties to achieve line 7 in document above..

Comment: ЕЕЕ! Gotcha! If spring_config_loaction isnt the file but the directory, and propsFile name is "application-dev.properties", and profile is "dev" Spring handles props from outer file! Thanks to all!

Comment: Furthermore, for better Spring compatibility its better to use not SPRING_CONFIG_LOCATION environment property, but spring.config.location - dot-separated version.

Answer (score 0):

One solution I found was to have the vm argument -Dloader.path with the external path when executing the application. Please keep in mind if you're using a fat jar you may need to create the package in Zip model, otherwise it will not work.